# Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'query.effects.core'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets

I'm getting this file not found error when I go to localhost:3000 when I start running my rails server.  The message I'm getting is `couldn't find file 'jquery.effects.core'`. I've pretty much done everything I can from pulling a new clone of the app from my repo to reinstalling Rails and Ruby, but it all leads to the same error. Any ideas?

I get the following output when I run my rails server:

```
sudo rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.

>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

and here's my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end

gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'
gem "therubyracer", '>= 0.11.0beta8', :require => 'v8'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
gem "less-rails"

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**EDIT (Solved)**: Here's my application.js file. Everything seems to work when I uncomment the `= require jquery` line. I don't know how to explain this because there are others working with the same set of source code that don't encounter this problem even though that line is commented out.

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery <----------------
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Could you post your `application.js` , please ?

Comment: I solved the problem by uncommenting = require jquery_ujs, but I'm still not sure why this is happening because others are working with the same source (with this line commented out) and aren't encountering this problem.

Comment: The syntax of the manifest files (as `application.js`) is strange . What exactly means you have uncommented , because the common insertion is like commented one in other languages . Anyway , it's nice to hear about the problem solved .

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I wasn't able to solve the problem. Turns out I didn't understand this file too well, so by uncommenting I meant that line became "= require jquery". It turns out that just broke Javascript altogether, allowing the site to load, but without Javascript enabled.

Comment: In this case , I think that by adding `/= require jquery` and `/= require jquery-ui` and removing (not commenting ;) `/= require tree .` it is going to be OK.

Comment: Still no such luck. Removing "/= require tree ." lets the site load, but Javascript is still broken.

Comment: Did you try : `/= require jquery.effects.core` in your application.js ?

Comment: Nope, but I fixed the problem as outlined by Greg Haygood's post. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in the RailsAdmin gem:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1471

Running 'bundle update' fixed this for me.

Comment: This looks like it's a similar problem, but unfortunately bundle update or even uninstall/reinstalling the rails_admin gem doesn't fix it.

Comment: "bundle update" didn't fix the problem, but I solved the problem by manually making the following change to rails_admin.js.erb:
-- require_asset 'jquery.effects.core'
++ require_asset 'jquery.ui.effects'